# Automatically updating two Excel sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two Excel sheets with the same columns, and I want a way by which if I update rows in one table, the corresponding rows in other tables are automatically also updated, and vice versa for both the tables?

Does a way like this exist? I searched a lot, but could not find the vice versa option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use some VBA to do this. Something like the following will work, which needs to be embedded in the script window for each sheet that contains your data. This assumes your data is in the same location on each sheet i.e. A1:A10.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'First Column
    Set KeyCells = Worksheets("sheet 1").Range("A1:A10")

    'Only undertake action if key cells are edited
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        'Edit second column
        Worksheets("sheet 2").Range(Target.Address) = Target.Value

    End If

End Sub
```

You'll obviously need to duplicate this to work for changes to sheet 2 and also and embedded the code in sheet 2.

Comment: What if the data is in different location. I have one file which has all the data, like data for all hospitals, and have other files which have data for hospital 1, hospital 2, hospital3, etc. But the fields are same in all the tables.
So the location of data in the file which has all the data, can have different location for each hospital data!

Comment: As long as each field is in the same column on each sheet you'll be fine. If not you'll need to augment the code to tell it the location of the column you want updated. If you're familiar with VBA have a play around with the above and change the range specified for the second column.